# HDIV Performance

Tags: jmeter, hdiv

Currently I am evaluating HDIV. Its a great tool to implement various levels of security. But currently I need to check its performance. ie after implementation of HDIV, what is the load time of my subsequent pages with _HDIV_STATE appended to the request.

But as this value is dynamically generated and is session/user/token specific, I am not able to configure the flow of events in JMeter. ie how do i get the generated value of HDIV_STATE which is dynamically generated and appended to my next link. Help on this will be highly appreciated.

You can also let me know in case if some other tool i can use to get this done. In short I need time ie if 100 users right now are accessing my website, what would the load times of the page with HDIV and without HDIV.

Answer (score 0):

It is classic "correlation" challenge example. Basically you need the following:

1. Execute 1st request
2. Extract _HDIV_STATE from the response and save it to JMeter Variable
3. Append the JMeter Variable to 2nd request
4. Repeat steps 1-4 for any subsequent request

Depending on response nature you can use the following Post Processor test elements:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - evaluate a Perl5-style regular expression against the response and store match value into a variable - should cover 90% of all needs
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) - designed to extract information from HTML pages using CSS selectors and/or JQuery syntax
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) - the same for XML and XHTML responses

See the following guides for step-by-step explanation on how to use above post processors:

- [Correlation in JMeter](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html)
- [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)